# how to create kendo combobox dynamically using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I am trying to create kendo combo box dynamically but it's not working. There's way using option but i want this to be also working.

This the code:

```
var lstDOM = angular.element('<select kendo-combo-box k-placeholder="Select" k-data-text-field="displayname" k-data-value-field="serviceid"  k-filter="contains"  k-auto-bind="false" k-data-source="serviceListDs"></select>');

      $compile(lstDOM)($scope);

    $('#test').append(lstDOM);
```

if you want me to provide dojo also. I will create and then give ..

Please help me anyone to achieve this.

Comment: what events trigger you appending?why are using jquery to append a angular element?

Comment: why aren't you using a ng-if statement to append the element on the page?

Comment: @madalinivascu - I can but i want use angular only to bind.

Comment: In some moment you will need to initialize the widget.. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/markup